# How to sync to Android frame rate

Tags: java, android, frame, synchronize

I'm looking for a way to synchronize some code activity to the Android display frame rate.  It's a short bit of code that will simply set the color of a small display region, nothing more.  Is there some sort of method or hook that I can exploit for this purpose?

I can use a timer running at very fast intervals successfully but the rendering appears to suffer from aliasing with the frame rate.  For example, my frame rate is 60 Hz so if I set the timer interval to 1/60 seconds, the appearance is non-uniform.  I can't set the timer to exactly 16.666 msec and even if I could, I'd still see aliasing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but I ran into this problem myself and created a nice little utility class that does exactly this.

Kotlin Class:

```kotlin
/**
 * Small utility class that allows for [doFrame] to be executed every frame based on the native
 * [Choreographer] instead of using precomputed values and timers.
 * [doFrame] is run on the main thread and is executed on the next frame.
 * The [SyncedRenderer] can be restarted freely.
 */
class SyncedRenderer(val doFrame: (frameTimeNanos: Long) -> Unit) {

    private var callback: (Long) -> Unit = {}

    fun start() {
        callback = {
            doFrame(it)
            Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(callback)
        }
        Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(callback)
    }

    fun stop() {
        Choreographer.getInstance().removeFrameCallback(callback)
        callback = {}
    }
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val renderer = SyncedRenderer { frameTimeNanos: Long ->
    // My code here will execute on main thread every frame
}

// Example when dragging something

override fun onStartDrag() {
    renderer.start()
}

override fun onReleaseDrag() {
    renderer.stop()
}
```

I found it was only marginally more performant than just using a fixed rate `Timer` and running the code every frame refresh rate.

However with this implementation you don't run any code on a backgroud thread so you don't need to call any kind of `post` or it's related methods when modifying `View`s.

More importantly though no extra execution is done than necessary so this can be very useful for more smooth scrolling and animating compared to when using a hardcoded refresh rate timer.

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day))) I've created a scheduled task for every 16.6ms using almost everything, handlers, executorSerivce, timers, but it was lagging. This solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching and experimenting, one solution is to use the Choreographer class which provides a way to hook a callback function into the frame rate. Below is the code. I found it shows sloppy timing on slow phones. Recent model Samsung phones perform better.

```
private FrameCallback frameCallback = null;
private boolean frameCallbackPending = false;

public void armVSyncHandler() {
    if(!frameCallbackPending) {
        frameCallbackPending = true;
        if(frameCallback == null)
        {
            frameCallback = new FrameCallback() {
                @Override
                public void doFrame(long frameTimeNanos) {
                    frameCallbackPending = false;

                    // Do some work here

                    armVSyncHandler();
                }
            };
        }
        Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(frameCallback);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyView extends View {

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // ...

            this.postInvalidateOnAnimation ();
    }
};
```

You may use the version taking a rectnagle:

```
 public void postInvalidateOnAnimation (int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
```

And there is also a way to do this using TimeAnimator. I think it's the most prefered way:

```
public class MyView extends View {
    public MyView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.timeAnimator.setTimeListener(this.timeListener);
        this.timeAnimator.start ();

    }
    private TimeAnimator.TimeListener timeListener = new TimeAnimator.TimeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeUpdate(TimeAnimator animation, long totalTime, long deltaTime) {
            MyView.this.invalidate();
        }
    };
};
```